# Contextual push messages and badge icon in FCM

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Up until now I have been using APNS and manually connection to their services over TCP. I have packaged and delivered all push notifications in a single operation by writing all of the combined data to APNS.

Things are moving along and Android is starting to become relevant, so I looked into FCM as a common platform for push.

I cannot figure out how I am supposed to send, let's say:

```
"Hello (username)! Blah Blah blah blah whatever"
```

... to many users at one.

The FCM docs allow me to specify multiple device tokens, which is great, but they will all receive the same notification. Is there no way to customize this per device/token? Also this is a big problem when it comes to the notification badge count in iOS. If everyone receives the same notification payload, they will also receive the same badge icon count.

Am I really to believe that I am supposed to make an HTTP request for *every single user* to make this work properly across both iOS and Android?

```
   {
      "registration_ids" : ["token1", "token2", "token3"], <--- devices
      "priority" : "normal",
      "notification" : {
        "body" : "Hello, Maria! Whatever blah blah", <-- Same message
        "title" : "Whatever",
        "badge" : "3" <--- all users receive the same? How?
      }
   }
```

I tried posting the payload as an array of above objects in a single request, but that does not work (as expected, since it's not documented).

How do we solve this?

Comment: I think this'll have to be handled on the client side at some point. But can only be possible for when the client app is the one that'll show the notification and not by the default device action (simply showing via the notification trays) themselves.

Comment: @AL. So in short, that's a "no solution" to the badge icon problem as far as you're aware.

Comment: In short there is no other solution to this. For every *different* message, you'll have to send it separately. Specially because of the badge. Unless, you can make a separate implementation for the badge itself. Like having a counter on the server/client side or something.

Comment: @AL. The problem is that there is no client-side way to modify the badge when the app is not running. It *must* be delivered with the APNS payload, unfortunately.